# Sum of terms in a geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The formula to find sum of n terms of a geometric progression is
>
> $\dfrac{a(r^n - 1)}{r - 1}$ if $r\gt 1$
>
> $\dfrac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ if $r\lt 1$

This is the definition we can see in all books. But, why these separate definitions are needed? Regardless of $r \gt 1$ or  $r \lt 1$, both these formulas can be used because numerator and denominator will be equally affected. So, there is no point in having two separate formulas because both are indeed same. Is my understanding right or is there any specific objective for having these formulas seperate?

Also, why no books define sum of n terms when $r=1$. The sum of $n$ terms in that case should be $an$. Am I correct here?

Comment: Separate definitions are not needed. In fact, both formulas are equal: just multiply the numerator and denominator by $-1$ to see this.

Comment: To answer your last question, if $r=1$ then you are just adding $n$ copies of $a$, so the result is $na$.

Comment: @Bungo, exactly. I am confused because of these two definitions in my text books which was not needed

Comment: You're correct; probably it's written separately this way sometimes (I've never seen it this way), so that the relevant factors are positive. Of course, when $r = 1$, the sum is $a n$, which coincides with the limit of (either) expression as $r \to 1$.

Comment: I think this has been done to keep both the numerator and denominator separately positive (perhaps to enhance ease of calculation??), so that one can write $\frac{2}{2}$ and not $\frac{-2}{-2}$. However, of course there is no real difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two formulae are the same with sign reversed above and below. Maybe they used the second formula when $|r|<1$ because then it is easier to see

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n = 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}=\frac a{1-r}$$